# how to implement N-tier architecture to get SSRS report

Tags: web, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, n-tier-architecture

i am developing a web application which access the ssrs report

In the app first the user has to login to the application.

Once the user is authenticated he is redireccted to ReportSelection.aspx

There are different types of reports developed in SSRS like R1,R2,R3.
First they have to select the Name of the student and then report.

do I have to use reportViewer control? There should be DAL,BL,UI and from the UI i will be calling a WCF service which calls the SSRS deployed in report server

i think it will return a dataset? 
by using this how can i display the SSRS report.
How to develop the application ?? steps please

Answer (score 0):

N-tier with WebForms?

I've done the following in the past:

- DB, Create SP's for reports
- EF, Map SP's to POCO's
- Repository, Manage EF context
- Service, Handle creating repositories / custom BL
- UI, Call service layer, map List objects to reportviewer.

Notes:

- Use DI/IoC
- You can't use reportviewer in remote mode in n-tier as it
  wants to call the SP's directly, so localmode and assign the datasets
  to the reportviewer control.